# Use LINQ for AddRange to Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, network-interface

Hello I try To Convert My old code to new version with Linq but i have problem for do it
old :

```
foreach (var item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    {
        lstTrace.Items.Add(item.Name);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
lstTrace.Items.Add(
    NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(nic => nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Name
);
```

But it just returns one result.
How can I get all found items?

Comment: You're calling the `FirstOrDefault` method. How many results were you expecting using that?

Comment: Keep your old code as is... It works and it is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend to create 'one-liner' code which spans for 5 lines and mixes both data selection and filling list view. Make both things easy to read and understand. Split (1) retrieving and filtering data with (2) assigning data to list view:

```
var ethernetInterfaceNames = 
       from i in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
       where i.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet
       select i.Name;

foreach(var name in ethernetInterfaceNames)
    lstTrace.Items.Add(name);
```

I would also move getting ethernet interface names to separate method or layer. Thus you will split business logic and presentation logic. You can use `AddRange` here, but it willl not make your code any simpler:

```
lstTrace.Items.AddRange(ethernetInterfaceNames.Select(n => new ListViewItem(n)).ToArray())
```

I believe simple foreach loop is far more readable.

Comment: as i understand you say me the old code is better than Linq version ?

Comment: @DavisMiller no. As you can see I suggest to use LINQ version, but in declarative query style which focuses on describing what you are selecting instead of how. I suggest not to mix presentation code with business logic. Your old code was tightly coupled mix - you were adding items to list view in the middle of selecting required items from network interfaces. Other approaches don't fix this issue, but just reverse it - data selection goes in the middle of adding items to list view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the AddRange method to add multiple items and then you just need to use select to get the Names of your nics.

Your current code is using `FirstOrDefault` which will only ever return a single value (the first) from your enumerable.

```
lstTrace.Items.AddRange(
    NetworkInterface
        .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(nic => nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        .Select(nic => nic.Name)
        .ToArray()
);
```

Additionally xanatos's comment on your question is worth repeating here. Your previous code worked fine, and was readable. Doing this with LINQ isn't going to make your code faster and I would probably say makes it harder to read if anything. While the above code should work I would seriously consider just keeping your original code.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you'll need a `ToArray()` (Winforms wasn't updated to LINQ-galore ) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
lstTrace.Items.AddRange(NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(nic => nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet).Select(a => a.Name).ToArray());
```

Comment: `Add` doesn't accept multiple items at once. `AddRange` would work for WinForms but not in WPF.

Comment: You need a `.ToArray()` on the end of that as well (as xanatos reminded me).

Comment: @HristoYankov: Have you got docs to back that up? Where I'm looking it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Its adding it to a `ListBox`, not a `List<string>`.

Comment: OK, my bad, I didn't see that it's a `Listbox`

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting one, because you are only *asking* for one: `FirstOrDefault` will give you the first member of the sequence or the type's default value if its empty.

What you need to do is project the sequence to what you really need using `Select`:

```
lstTrace.Items
        .AddRange(NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                                  .Where(nic => nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                                  .Select(item => item.Name));
```

Comment: @RomaDoskoch True! Copied and pasted and forgot to change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use AddRange

```
var projects = multi.Read<ProjectDto>();
var projectAct = multi.Read<ProjectActivity>();

foreach (var project in projects)
{
   project.ProjectActivities = new List<ProjectActivity>();                        
   project.ProjectActivities.AddRange(projectAct.Where(x => x.ProjectId == project.ProjectId));
}
```

Note: One cannot use the addrange on a data type IEnumerable only on the data type list.